# Setting video size in webRTC iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc

I'm using `RTCMediaConstraints` for creating RTCPeerConnection and sending SDP but I have feeling that my optional constraints related to video max width / height aren't respected.

```
- (RTCMediaConstraints *)mediaConstraints {

    RTCPair *audioConstraint = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyOfferToReceiveAudio value:kKeyTrue];
    RTCPair *videoConstraint = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyOfferToReceiveVideo value:kKeyTrue];

    RTCPair *sctpConstraint = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyInternalSctpDataChannels value:kKeyTrue];
    RTCPair *dtlsConstraint = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyDtlsSrtpKeyAgreement value:kKeyTrue];

    RTCPair *maxWidth = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyMaxWidth value:@"640"];
    RTCPair *minWidth = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyMinWidth value:@"320"];

    RTCPair *maxHeight = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyMaxHeight value:@"480"];
    RTCPair *minHeight = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyMinHeight value:@"240"];

    RTCPair *maxFrameRate = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyMaxFrameRate value:@"30"];
    RTCPair *minFrameRate = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyMinFrameRate value:@"24"];

    RTCPair *minAspectRatio = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minAspectRatio" value:@"4:3"];
    RTCPair *maxAspectRatio = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:kKeyMaxAspectRatio value:@"4:3"];

    return [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:@[audioConstraint, videoConstraint]
                                                 optionalConstraints:@[sctpConstraint, dtlsConstraint, maxAspectRatio, minAspectRatio, minFrameRate, maxFrameRate, maxWidth, minWidth, maxHeight, minHeight]];
}
```

When I include constraings for RTCVideoSource I see only black screen without video.

```
RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:[device localizedName]];
RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [_peerFactory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:[self mediaConstraints]];
RTCVideoTrack *videoTrack = [_peerFactory videoTrackWithID:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] source:videoSource];

[_localMediaStream addVideoTrack:videoTrack];
```

Does someone have some suggestion about this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at RTCMediaConstraints.h file of WebRTC, there is no keys for kKeyOfferToReceiveAudio and kKeyOfferToReceiveVideo. These statements are not supported in RTCMediaConstraints and it may be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience with WebRTC constraints, a black screen means a faulty constraint.

Also, I don't think you should put the offer and DTLS constraint on a video source, if that is what you were doing.

That's pretty much all I can tell you.

Comment: I saw that Google sample code uses DTLS constraints for video. That leed me think it will be OK. Thanks for your answer.